# Text selection using shift + direction stopped working after updating my mac to El Capitan

Tags: texstudio, mac

Before updating my Mac to El Capitan I used to select text via pressing shift + arrows. After updating it doesn't work. What happened? Already tried to remove texStudio and install it again. It did not help.

Comment: If this happens in any text editor this question is most likely off-topic

Comment: Welcome! Congratulations if this is the only thing which doesn't work following the upgrade ;). But this is probably off-topic. Although I'm not sure. It can't be Cocoa if it is TeX Studio. Does OS X still have TextEdit? Or some other default text editor? What happens there?

Comment: In TextEdit and other editors everything is ok. Problem appears only in TexStudio editor

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you what happened, but I can tell you how to fix it.

Open up the Preferences window (shortcut is cmd-,), and then click on the "Shortcuts" tab. Find the heading called "Basic Key Mapping", and click on the triangle next to it to uncollapse that section. Now find the command called "Select left (1 character)", and change its shortcut by double-clicking its current shortcut and editing it. Change it to be shift-left. You can do similar things for the commands "Select right (1 character)", "Select up", and "Select down".

Additionally, if pressing cmd-right or cmd-left doesn't move your cursor to the end of the line as you might want it to, you can also change the shortcuts to the commands "Move cursor to line end" and "Move cursor to line start".

Hope this helps!